# How do you link fonts in to Quill 1.0?

Tags: quill

I just started using 1.0 and want to use different font faces. I am currently using

```
    quill.format(range_start, range_end, 'font', 'serif');
```

But it isn't working. I checked the documentation and this seems to be what you are supposed to do (when not using the toolbar).

I have tried using all sorts of other formats and they work just fine, I just can't get the font to change and show up as an attribute when exported (need it to be in object, not just appear to user).

How can I use different font with Quill?

Answer (score 0):

`format()` operates on the current selection, not any arbitrary location. You want to use [`formatText()`](http://beta.quilljs.com/docs/api/#formattext). Also another issue is all of Quill's functions are index/length based rather than start/end.

Comment: Even if I use quill.formatText('font', 'monospace');

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class with the appropriate font name after it in this format:

```
.ql-font-fontname { font-family:'fontname'}
```